# How to use one table attribute or its value as a Constraint on another table's attribute

Tags: sql, oracle

I am making  database for housing society management system . I have following two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE PLOT ( plotID number(3) PRIMARY KEY,
                    blockName char REFERENCES blockINFO, 
                    ownerID number(13) REFERENCES OWNER,
                    status varchar2(10) NOT NULL, 
         CONSTRAINT PLOT_CONS CHECK ((Status IN ('SOLD', 'UNSOLD'))) );

CREATE TABLE HOUSE (houseID number(3) PRIMARY KEY, 
                    plotID number(3)  REFERENCES PLOT )
         CONSTRAINT PLOT_CONS CHECK (plotID (Status NOT IN ( 'UNSOLD'))) );
```

I want to apply Constraint on attribute of `HOUSE` table that is --> plotiID (foreign key) & Constraint should not allow user to enter any `plotID` in `HOUSE` table if its **status** is **'UNSOLD'** in `PLOT` table.

I tried this. but it is not working:

`CONSTRAINT PLOT_CONS CHECK (plotID (status IN('SOLD')));`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Always include the DBMS tag on SQL questions.

Comment: You probably should handle thatt with a trigger instead a constrain

Comment: how can I do this through trigger

Comment: Check this [***Example***](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37582/plsql-before-insert-trigger) for `BEFORE INSERT` trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `BEFORE INSERT` trigger is the most suitable way to handle this. You can use it to check all the conditions you need before the insertion actually happens. Something like the following will help you.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkPlotStatus
BEFORE INSERT 
    ON HOUSE
DECLARE
    plot_status VARCHAR(10);
BEGIN
    --Get the plot status for the plot id you are trying to insert
    SELECT status INTO plot_status
    FROM PLOT
    WHERE plotID=:new.plotID;

    --If that status is UNSOLD, then raise an application error.
    --Else, do the insertion
    IF plot_status = 'UNSOLD' THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Status of plot is unsold!');
    ELSE
         INSERT INTO HOUSE
         VALUES (:new.houseID, :new.plotID);
    ENDIF;
END;
/
```

More information on Oracle triggers:https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/triggers.htm